# Concurrent access of List of Map in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

I have the following List.

```
 List<Map<String,String>> input = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
```

I have a requirement where each Map object in List is accessed in threads.
It is guarenteed no two threads access the same map object.

```
for(Map<String,String> input : inputList){
    triggerThread(input); // Thread modifies the input. It adds elements in the input map
}
```

Do I need to use synchronizedList(inputList) or  synchronizedmap(input) or is it OK to use input map directly without any  synchronization logic? Which is the good design?

This might be the basic question. I am quite confused on how to implement.

```
   class Main{
      public static void main(String[] args){
       List<Map<String,String>> inputList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
       Map<String,String> input = new HashMap<String,String>();
       input.put("attr1","param1");
       inputList.add(input);
       ExecutorService pool= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
       for(Map<String,String> input : inputList){
         RequestHandler request = new RequestHandler(input);
         pool.submit(request);
        }
      }
   }

     class RequestHandler extends Runnable{
         Map<String,String> input;
         RequestHandler(Map<String,String> input){
           this.input=input;
         }
        @Override
         public void run() {
           //writing logic vaguely
           input.add("attr2", "param2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't modify a list when looping through it, you will get a ConcurrentModificationException. Use the iterator for that. You still need to synchronize.

Comment: The example code never modifies the list, consequently there will never be a ConcurrentModificationException thrown.

Comment: Here I am just modifying object in list.  I am not removing or adding elements to the list. So we might not get ConcurrentModificationException. can you help me in synchronizing list.

Comment: @Teja, can you post the code for `triggerThread ()` ?

Comment: It also depends on when, where and how you create the list relative to the threads which read from it. I don't think we can accurately answer your question without seeing all of your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: In your extended sample, the map values are never read - is this because this is just part of larger app?

Comment: Map values will be accessed in the thread.  I just removed that part. Yea  its a  part of larger app.

Comment: I strongly feel there is no need to use synchronization logic in this case. 
As modification to the map doesnt not effect the list size. I usually visualize it as Map is in distinct memory and its memory address  is stored in list.
But a bit of doubt is hitting me if this is the correct behavior will it affect the list size. Adding elements to the maps of two list objects can cause any synchronization issue to the list.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html especially the bit about visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- The `inputList` list is populated by one thread, and then it is not modified (i.e. no elements are added/removed) by other threads
- No two threads access the same map object in the `input` map (as the question states)

If this is the case, then there is no need to synchronize on `inputList` nor on `input`.

If, on the other hand, you will access `inputList` itself by other threads, use [Collections.syncrhonizedList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List).) for example.

Comment: This is not always correct, for example if the list is created and/or populated after the reader threads have been started and is not final or is final but populated after its assignment. See [17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), [17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) and [17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).

Comment: As I am not changing inputList and only modifying object referenced by the list elements which are not visible elsewhere I feel Hinson suggestion works in this case. I need not use any synchronization logic in this case.

Comment: I strongly feel there is no need to use synchronization logic in this case. As modification to the map doesnt not effect the list size. I usually visualize it as Map is in distinct memory and its memory address is stored in list. But a bit of doubt is hitting me if this is the correct behavior will it affect the list size. Adding elements to the maps of two list objects, can it cause any synchronization issue to the list.

Comment: @Teja: the fact that you add new elements to the maps does not change the inputList. The `inputList` contains *references* (or pointers) to the maps. These references do not change (only the underling maps change).

Answer (score 0):

Since the list never changes and is in effect immutable, your only concern are the Map elements. It is possible that changes made by one thread to a Map element may not be visible to another thread. To solve this you can use ConcurrentHashMap:

e.g.:

```
    List<Map<String,String>> input = new ArrayList<>();
    input.add(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    ...
```

For reference, have a look at [this](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html) especially the bit about visibility